# Scanner on HP Network multifunction printer in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hp-laserjet

I have installed a new multifunction printer HP Color LaserJet PRO MFP M176n
using the hplip I have managed to setup the printer parter working ok.
hp-setup allowed a good install of the printer but I don't see how to install the network scanner.

Any idea on how I can do this?